# How do I access the source of a GUI event in PowerShell?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I making a menu of checkable items in a PowerShell script, like this:

```
"Red", "Green", "Blue" | %{
    $mi = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem($_)
    $mi.CheckOnClick = $true
    $mi.add_CheckedChanged({
        $name = # label of the menu item that was checked
        doStuff $name
    })
    ...
}
```

How do I access the menu item that was checked from the CheckedChanged event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the label of a [ToolStripMenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.aspx) is stored in its Text property and since in a PowerShell [event handler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/05/24/wpf-powershell-part-3-handling-events.aspx) $this is bound to the event sender, the label of the menu item is available in the event handler as:

```
$this.Text
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! (I'd been trying $_, but I guess that's bound to args)

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell 2.0, you would use the `$Sender` automatic variable within the `Action` scriptblock passed into an event registration command such as `Register-ObjectEvent` e.g.:

```
PS> Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
PS> $form = new-object system.windows.forms.form
PS> $button = new-object system.windows.forms.button -prop @{Text = "Click me"}
PS> $job = Register-ObjectEvent $button Click -Action `
           {"Button with text: $($Sender.Text) clicked."}
PS> $form.Controls.Add($button)
PS> $form.ShowDialog()
Cancel
PS> Receive-Job $job
Button with text: Click me clicked.
```

Comment: Good information, thanks! (I gave it to Rick because I could plug "this.Text" into what I was already doing -- I didn't know about Register-ObjectEvent and Action blocks).